# Strange TypeError occured when calling method function exposed by boost python

Tags: python, boost-python

I write a python wrapper for box2d, everything work perfect but a strange TypeError error occurs sometimes when calling method function exposed by boost python. It's a random behavior, not happened every time.

The problem python code:

```
try:
    world = body.GetWorld()  # world is b2World instance, body is b2Body instance
    world.DestroyBody(body)  # raise TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
except TypeError:  # catch it, and print some infomation
    print "xxxxx", world  # I got a b2World instance here
    print "xxxxx", sys.getrefcount(world)  # I got a value of 66 here
    print "xxxxx", world.DestroyBody  # I got a bound method object here
    raise
```

It seems all okay. How does that happened?

And part of my wrapper code:

```
// [file]: https://github.com/layzerar/box2d-py/blob/master/python/world.cpp
// [project]: https://github.com/layzerar/box2d-py
template<class T>
inline void b2Func_ClearUserData(T& self)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    xdecref((PyObject*)self.GetUserData());
    self.SetUserData(NULL);
}
inline void b2World_DestroyBody(b2World& self, b2Body* body)
{
    b2Assert(self.GetBodyCount() > 0);
    b2Assert(self.IsLocked() == false);

    b2Func_ClearUserData(*body);
    self.DestroyBody(body);
}
class_<b2World, b2World_W , boost::noncopyable>("b2World")
    //...
    .def("CreateBody", b2World_CreateBody, return_internal_reference<>())
    .def("DestroyBody", b2World_DestroyBody)
    //...
;
```

Did I make an obvious mistake?

Comment: Environment: python 2.6.5, boost 1.49.0, visual studio 2010

Comment: How can I run your code?

Comment: @Satoru.Logic    I'm sorry, It's hard to paste all my python code. But if you intersted about it, you could check out the v2.2.2 branch from my project, it could be compiled with VS or G++ easily(boost is required). The usage is almost  the same as C++ version of box2d, and it's work nice. The issue cannot be reappeared just by the code above and I have no idea about how to reappear it even.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days exploring I found the answer.

I make a mistake about the question, the exception is really not thrown by DestroyBody. It's thrown by a virtual function which is rewrite in python and called in DestroyBody function.